# ResourceGroup deployment fails with 'LinkedAuthorizationFailed' error while trying to set WebApp certificate from Keyvault in a different subscription

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am receiving the following error while trying to execute a resource group deployment.

LinkedAuthorizationFailed

"The client '' with object id '' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/certificates/write' on scope /subscriptions/<*subscriptionid1*>/resourcegroups/<*rgname1*>/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/certificatename'; however, it does not have permission to 
perform action 'write' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/<*subscriptionid2*>/resourceGroups/<*rgname2*>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvault01'."

The ARM template is trying to fetch a certificate from a Keyvault which resides in a **different subscription**. The template is being deployed using a Service Principal and has got *reader* permission on the KeyVault.

This works fine if I set *contributor* role or a custom role with "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write" permission on the Keyvault for the service principal. I have ensured that Microsoft.Azure.WebSites have GET permission and "Enable Access to Azure Resource Manager for template deployment" checked.

The ARM template is similar to what you can see here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-certificate-from-key-vault

Any ideas on why this fails with 'reader' role. granting write on Keyvault sounds like assigning more privileges than required.

Comment: ok, if this works as a contributor something has changed and I dont really have up to date information on this subject anymore. sorry ;) but I assume you need to grant something like `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/read` permission to actually do this

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm with the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

To access secrets and certificates in key vaults you need to grant permissions via "Access Policies"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error when I used the wrong resource group name.